# Is it possible to request access to a document using Google Drive API?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API (via Java client) with authorized requests. When I tried to download a file which I don't have access to, it returns file not found. Is it possible to request access using the authorized account via Google Drive API?

Comment: You can only access files that the currently authenticated user has access to.  The only way i know of to request access would be though the Google drive web application when you try to open a file you dont have access to it will notify the owner.  I dont think thats something the API has the power to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is no method of the Drive API that allows you to ask for permission for access to a file. The only way of obtaining the access is by visiting the URL of the file and pressing the `Request access` button, or directly asking the owner of the file.*