# Request access to Google Spreadsheet file

Tags: python, spreadsheet, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to request access to file via API but fail API returns error as a result:

> Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u...4bcSqdgc/edit#gid=0.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]"

But if I try to open this link in browser - I see correct message, that you don't have access to file:

> "please input message and post the access request"

I have following API's enabled in Console:

> Google Drive API BigQuery API BigQuery Migration API BigQuery Storage API Cloud Datastore API Cloud Logging API Cloud Monitoring API Cloud SQL Cloud Storage Cloud Storage API Cloud Trace API Gmail API Google Cloud APIs Google Cloud Storage JSON API Resource Settings API Service Management API Service Usage API

Code is as follows:

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=g.gcreds_scoped)

permission_request = { 'role': 'writer', 'type': 'anyone', 'allowFileDiscovery': False }

sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=g.gcreds_scoped)

request = drive_service.permissions().create(body=permission_request, fileId=file_url, supportsAllDrives=True, fields='id')

response = request.execute()
```

Checked API's enabled, everything seems fine
Looks like Google API has unfixed bug and this does not work correctly, or I have missed something?

Comment: details from import section: from googleapiclient.discovery import build

Answer (score 0):

I guessed that from your error message of `'message': 'File not found: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u...4bcSqdgc/edit#gid=0.'`, you might use the URL as the file ID. So, I guessed that `file_url` of `fileId=file_url` might be `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u...4bcSqdgc/edit#gid=0`. If my understanding is correct, this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, please use the file ID instead of the URL.

If your current value of `file_url` is `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u...4bcSqdgc/edit#gid=0`, please modify it to `1u...4bcSqdgc`. Please use your correct file ID (In this case, it's Spreadsheet ID.) And, test it again.

If the Spreadsheet URL is `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit#gid=0`, `###` is the Spreadsheet ID. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your client of `drive_service` can access the Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.
- About `But if i try to open this link in browser - I see correct message , that you don't have access to file - "please input message and post the access request"`, if your client of `drive_service` cannot access to the Spreadsheet, it is indicated that you have no permission. In that case, even when the above modification is reflected in your script, the permission of the Spreadsheet cannot be changed. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Google Sheets API Overview](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)

Comment: Thank you for your correction, but still , as you mentioned above - this doesn't create request for access to this file from author.

Does anyone know how to create such request via API?

Comment: @Art Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Thank you for your correction, but still , as you mentioned above - this doesn't create request for access to this file from author. Does anyone know how to create such request via API?`, if both your account and the author of the file are in a Google Workspace and the administrator permits you to change the permission of the file, you can do it. But, if both accounts are Gmail accounts and other Google Workspaces, unfortunately, I think that this cannot be achieved. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this issue here:
[Is it possible to request access to a document using Google Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115742/is-it-possible-to-request-access-to-a-document-using-google-drive-api)

In a nutshell - there is no way to request access via API